# How to solve $14t - 4.9t^2 = -4.9(t-2)^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics

I am studying for a physics exam using a textbook written by my professor for my course. In it there is a step-by-step solution to a problem, and I cannot figure out how to go from one step to the next. Basically we arrived at

$$14t  - 4.9t^2 = -4.9(t-2)^2$$

How (This is where he loses me) do we conclude $0.8t = 2.8$?

I am not sure what is going on to go from one step to the next. If I am ignorant to something simple, or if you have an explanation, or links to an explanation I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: To go from the text above your bold (This is where he loses me), just simplify the first equation to get the second (the $t^2$ terms cancel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By expanding one gets
$$
-4.9(T-2)^2=-4.9\times T^2+4.9\times(4T)-4.9\times4=-4.9\: T^2+19.6\:T-19.6
$$ then the equation
$$
14T-4.9\: T^2=-4.9(T-2)^2
$$ reads
$$
14\:T-19.6\:T=-19.6
$$ that is (simplifying and dividing by $-7$)
$$
0.8\:T=2.8
$$ as announced.

Comment: Thank you kindly. I tried to upvote this answer, but I do not have enough reputation to do so, but do know that I am eternally grateful. :D

Comment: @Aezur You are welcome. You can just *accept* the answer (with the button on the left).

Comment: Ah yes, I see. I have done so. If I may... What is it called when I expand the -4.9(T-2)^2 ?  It is this bit that is tripping me up, and I realise that I just do not know how to do it, so I am trying to find a proper explanation, but I am finding it hard to google it without a name.

Comment: @Aezur I would call it expanding brackets.

Comment: @Olivier Oloa You are a life saver. That's exactly the piece of the puzzle I was missing. Thank you.

Comment: It comes from $(a−b)^2=a^2−2ab+b^2$.